# How to trace zombie memory (inactive but not leak, sleep status) in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, memory

Using instrument and find my app has consumed too much memory, I want to profile it. It has very little memory leak, so I concern it maybe dues to some zombie memory (inactive but not leak, sleep status), but it doesn’t belong to leak. How can I find such kind of memory?

For example, if we don’t do [NSTimer invalidate], then dealloc won’t be invoked, how can I find such cases?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting from the menu, Product -> Analyze maybe?